# Change Excel row background color based on day of week on 1st column

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched and looked at similar questions but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I'd like to set the background of a row to a certain color based on the day of week (Mon is green, Tues is red, Sun is yellow, etc.) value of date that is entered in column A.

Can someone help me with the VBA code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBA code should do it:

Reference documentation for [Weekday](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/weekday-HP005209336.aspx) and [ColorIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

I didn't check if the colors are the correct for the day; the proper values can be found in the documentation I linked.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        For Each Cell In Target
            Select Case Weekday(Cell.Value)

                Case Is = 1
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 1

                Case Is = 2
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 2

                Case Is = 3
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                Case Is = 4
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 4

                Case Is = 5
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 5

                Case Is = 6
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

                Case Is = 7
                    Cell.Columns("A:J").Interior.ColorIndex = 7

            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Much appreciated jpw. I believe I'd need to incorporate your code into the Worksheet SelectionChange of column A it will be called but don't know how to do that. Also, what change do I need so that the code will work dynamically, i.e. when I enter date in column A this will be triggered? I don't know how many rows I will have so range A1:A10 will not work. My apologies for not being clearer in my original question.

Comment: @Yuri I've updated my question, I believe it should do what you want now. I think using the SelectionChange might be a bad idea and that Worksheet_Change might be better.

Comment: jpw your code is working, much thanks! Worksheet_Change works for me since only column A contains date. How do I limit color change to only 10 columns instead of entire row?

Comment: @Yuri Updated again. Now only columns A:J changes color for the row in with date in column A is changed.

Comment: jpw, your code works perfectly now and achieves everything I need. Really appreciated your help. I'd also like to thanks everyone for your input. You guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** : I only noticed after posting a conditional formatting example that a VBA solution was asked.

Using conditional formatting, you could try this:

1. Enter some dates in your sheet
2. Apply the `WEEKDAY` function to them like so `=WEEKDAY(CELLREF)`. This will return a number from one to 7 indicating the day of the week.
3. Apply conditional formatting to give each day its color using the "Cell value equal to" rule:

[image: A sheet with some dates]

next the rules:

[image: 2 rules applied]

A specific rule:

[image: Specific for Sundays...]

This is only for Sunday and another day but you should be able to select the colors for the other days just fine.

Mind you I'm running Excel on a mac but on Windows, you should find the conditional formatting here:

[image: On Windows]

A more elaborate description of conditional formatting and dates is [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-excels-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-weekends/)

**EDIT**

To format the entire row using conditional formatting:

1. Select the row
2. Go to the conditional formatting interface
3. Select "Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format"
4. Refer to the "reference" cell in the row selection and enter a formula e.g. `=$C5=1`
5. in the same way, do the colors for the other days

You will get something like:

[image: Formatting based on rule]

and:

[image: Specific rule]

Which will result in:

[image: Sunday!]

Changing the date of the cell:

[image: Green!]

Comment: Thanks Kris. I'd like the row color to change when I enter a date in column A.

Comment: hmm I noticed just now... I'll adjust/amend.

Comment: @Yuri it can be done using conditional formatting. I edited my post to a more specific solution for your issue.

Comment: @pnuts then OP should be smart enough to figure out that he can apply the conditional formatting to any number of columns by just selecting a range and next applying the "Use a formula to determine..." conditional formatting rules :) Anyway... he clearly needs VBA. I'll leave my answer up as an alternative but if need be I can always remove it.